# How do i change the modification/creation date of a folder

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin, touch

For my makefile creating folders on **Windows**, i need to update folders dates. When i have a newer subfolder, the parent Folders rule will allways be executed even if it exists, cause its date is not updated.

However `touch`only works with files. `touch` on a folder gives `touch: creating 'testDir': Permission denied`.
Is there a command to change dates of folders?

Please ask away if you need an example.

Comment: Use `touch` for existing folders, too.

Comment: `touch` command works on folders too..
`[root@client1 ~]# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 15 root root 4096 Jun 11 18:43 /tmp
[root@client1 ~]# touch /tmp
[root@client1 ~]# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 15 root root 4096 Jun 11 19:22 /tmp
[root@client1 ~]#`

Comment: You are right, i just checked this on Linux. The Problem is obviously the Windows file aystem where all folders are write protected. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!

Simply create an empty file in this folder, then delete it. Modification time is updated! [Thanks to Lyle Brown](https://superuser.com/questions/147524/how-to-automatically-update-folder-modified-date-in-windows)